# Removing an interval within another interval?

Tags: list-manipulation, intervals

Suppose we have the interval

`Interval[{-5,5}]`

How do we remove an interval from within this interval?

For example, if we wanted to remove `Interval[{-3,3}]` from `Interval[{-5,5}]` we would get `Interval[{-5,-3},{3,5}]`.

I looked in the mathematica documentations and searched through previous questions but could not find anything.

Comment: There is a function that does that in the wolfram function [repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntervalComplement). You can use ResourceFunction["IntervalComplement"][Interval[{-5, 5}], 
 Interval[{-3, 3}]].

Comment: I use the wolfram website to read documentation and typing complement i found that under "Wolfram Language Documentation". I am using linux and do not have the documentation installed but maybe if you write complement in the documentation search box that function will also appear.

Comment: You can also write a custom function using  `IntervalMemberQ` first to check whether the second interval is completely contained in the first, extract the list inside Interval using `Level[Interval[{-5, 5}],{2}]` and then `Interval @@ Partition[Sort[{-5, 5}~Join~{-3, 3}], 2]`.

Comment: Intervals are regions, `RegionQ[Interval[{-5,5}]]` yields `True`, but unfortunately `RegionDifference[Interval[{-5,5}],Interval[{-3,3}]]` does not return something useful. But `Line` works, try `RegionDifference[Line[{{-5},{5}}],Line[{{-3},{3}}]]`, and one could translate from `Interval` to `Line` and back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that this is not built-in to Mathematica suggests that there are some non-trivial subtleties.  However, I offer the following simple implementation

```
IntervalComplement[Interval[{a_, b_}]] := 
 Interval[{-∞, a}, {b, ∞}]
IntervalComplement[Interval[a__List]] := 
 IntervalIntersection @@ IntervalComplement@*Interval /@ {a}
IntervalDifference[a_Interval, b_Interval] := 
 IntervalIntersection[a, IntervalComplement[b]]
```

Test cases

```
int1 = Interval[{-5, 5}];
int2 = Interval[{-3, 3}];
int3 = Interval[{-5, -3}, {3, 5}];
IntervalComplement /@ {int1, int2, int3}
(* {Interval[{-∞, -5}, {5, ∞}], 
 Interval[{-∞, -3}, {3, ∞}], 
 Interval[{-∞, -5}, {-3, 3}, {5, ∞}]} *)
```

For your example, we have

```
IntervalDifference[int1, int2] == int3
(* True *)
```